# How can I change the fields displayed by dataTables?

Tags: relationships, ajax

I want to customize the information provided by templates that are generated via the dataTable plugin. Specifically, I want to alter the RelationshipSelector.tpl to display a contact's title and a couple of custom fields.

The dataTable script in the RelationshipSelector table makes a call to civicrm/ajax/contactrelationships via AJAX. It returns JSON. I noticed that the dataTable plugin elsewhere makes calls to civicrm/ajax/*.

Is there a way I can alter the JSON that is returned to include my fields?

I'm running a Drupal + Civi 4.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look in CRM/Core/xml/Menu/Contact.xml you'll see that the civicrm/ajax/contactrelationships maps to CRM_Contact_Page_AJAX::getContactRelationships, so you can go into CRM/Contact/Page/AJAX.php and change what the getContactRelationships function does.

If you're not familiar with the techniques [here](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Customize+Built-in+Screens) to override core files, as opposed to editing the actual core files, you also want to take a look at that.